# Parboiled2: How to process dependent fields?

Tags: scala, parboiled2

I'm trying to parse a file format, using the excellent [parboiled2](http://parboiled2.org/) library, in which the presence of some fields is dependent upon the value of one or more fields already processed.

For example, say I have two fields, the first of which is a flag indicating whether the second is present. That is, if the first field is `true`, then the second field (which is an integer value, in this example) is present and must be processed - but if it's `false`, then the second field isn't present at all. Note that this second field isn't *optional* - it either *must* be processed (if the first field is `true`) or *must not* be processed (if the first field is `false`).

So, if a third field (which we'll assume is always present) is a quoted string, both of the following lines are valid:

```
true 52 "Some quoted string"
false "Some other quoted string"
```

But this would be invalid:

```
false 25 "Yet another quoted string"
```

Ignoring the third field, how do I write a rule to parse the first two? (I can't tell from the documentation, and *Googling* hasn't helped so far...)

**UPDATE**: I should clarify that I can't use rules like the following, because the format I'm parsing is actually a lot more complicated than my example:

```
import org.parboiled2._

class MyParser(override val input: ParserInput)
extends Parser {

  def ws = // whitepsace rule, puts nothing on the stack.

  def intField = // parse integer field, pushes Int onto stack...

  def dependentFields = rule {
    ("true" ~ ws ~ intField) | "false" ~> //etc.
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: I've revised the following to make my intent clearer:

What I'm looking for is a valid equivalent to the following (non-existent) rule that performs a match only if a condition is satisfied:

```
import org.parboiled2._

class MyParser(input: ParserInput)
extends Parser {

  def ws = // whitepsace rule, puts nothing on the stack.

  def intField = // parse integer field, pushes Int onto stack...

  def boolField = // parse boolean field, pushes Boolean onto stack...

  def dependentFields = rule {
    boolField ~> {b =>

      // Match "ws ~ intField" only if b is true. If match succeeds, push Some(Int); if match
      // fails, the rule fails. If b is false, pushes None without attempting the match.
      conditional(b, ws ~ intField)
    }
  }
}
```

That is, `ws ~ intField` is only matched if `boolField` results in a `true` value. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can implement such a function with the help of `test` parser action:

```
def conditional[U](bool: Boolean, parse: () => Rule1[U]): Rule1[Option[U]] = rule {
  test(bool) ~ parse() ~> (Some(_)) | push(None)
}
```

According to the [Meta-Rules section](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#meta-rules) of the documentation, it can work only by passing a function to produce rules. You'd have to define `dependentFields` rule as follows:

```
def dependentFields = rule {
  boolField ~> (conditional(_, () => rule { ws ~ intField }))
}
```

---

**Update:**

While `test(pred) ~ opt1 | opt2` is a common technique, it *does* backtrack and tries to apply `opt2`, if `test` is successful `test`, but `opt1` fails. Here are two possible solutions to prevent such backtracking.

You can use `~!~` rule combinator, that has "cut" semantics and prohibits backtracking over itself:

```
def conditional2[U](bool: Boolean, parse: () => Rule1[U]): Rule1[Option[U]] = rule {
  test(bool) ~!~ parse() ~> (Some(_)) | push(None)
}
```

Or you actually use `if` *outside* of a rule to check the boolean argument and return one of two possible rules:

```
def conditional3[U](bool: Boolean, parse: () => Rule1[U]): Rule1[Option[U]] =
  if (bool) rule { parse() ~> (Some(_: U)) } 
  else rule { push(None) }
```

Comment: Thanks! This (almost) works! I understand that the meta-rules require functions (the docs are clear on that). I guess I didn't realize that I could use an | clause to push a value if the `test` action fails. That's nice! Unfortunately, that clause will also execute if the parse operation itself fails - so I can't distinguish between a false test condition and a failure to parse the `ws ~ intField` rule. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then again, when I test it, it does appear to do exactly what is required. Can you elaborate a little on how it works? In particular, I'm a little puzzled how the | clause doesn't appear to execute if the parse rule (`ws ~ intField`, in this example) fails to match? Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @MikeAllen I could reproduce the problem in your comment. Probably it was working for you because, you were matching `EOI` or something else incompatible after the `dependentFields` rule, and that caused the parser to fail. I've now updated the answer with two possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update - that's brilliant! I'll have to check what's going on in my test code, but I was expecting the behavior you describe. Using `~!~` works for me. I wasn't sure whether it was legal to have multiple `rule`s in a single function (as, say, `if...else` expressions), but that's good to know too. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting the right answers, but it seems for the wrong reasons. And there's no difference between using `~`or `~!~` after the `test` condition. I have a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/MichaelJAllen/parboiled2-condition) with both versions (`master` branch with cut, `nocut` branch without). If have a moment, I'd be very grateful if you could check the results and see what I may have done wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeAllen You'll see different behaviour between cut and no-cut versions with the test: `eval(new TestParser("true \"Should be Failure because intField is missing\""))`. `~!~` version fails, but no-cut version just pushes `None` successfully. In the test `true ha "foo"` no-cut version seems to work correctly, because the parser can't match this `ha` against any other rule, so it fails completely.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
extends Parser {

  def dependentFields: Rule1[(Boolean, Option[Int], String)] = rule {
     ("true" ~ ws ~ trueBranch | "false" ~ ws ~ falseBranch)
  }

  def trueBranch = rule {
     intField ~ ws ~ stringField ~> { (i, s) => (true, Some(i), s) }
  }

  def falseBranch = rule {
     stringField ~> { s => (false, None, s) }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MikeAllen if your logic is still branching on a boolean value I would say my approach (and your original approach) is valid. Otherwise I don't have enough input on your data structure to make a valid assumption on how to parse it.

Comment: Maybe my example is too trivial (as I indicated in my update). As it happens, I'm not branching on a Boolean value. In my real case, it would be more accurate to say that the first field is actually a bit-field of 10 flags, each of which determines whether other data - some distance away from the bit-field (i.e. not immediately following it) - is present. So what I'm trying to convey is a need to parse a field only if some expression is true. Does that clarify my issue?